# Table Design in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a requirement that requires a table design , where need to maintain the files uploaded for any applications. Is there a simple way I can achieve this with out any trigger/Sproc?

```
ID        AppName FileName    fileorder 
1          abc    file1        1
2          abc    file2        2
3          abc    file1        3
4          xyz    test1        1    - start a fresh 
5          xyz    test2        2
6          abc    file3        4    - resume from previous value of 'abc' 
7          xyz    test3        3    - resume from previous value of 'xyz'
8          grt    file1        1    - start a fresh
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing you can write in a CREATE TABLE that will automatically populate the `fileorder` column this way.   The only way you can do this is with some custom coding.

I don't know your reason for wanting to create a column like this in your table, but for most reasons I can think of, you're probably better off not storing this value in your table at all and either calculating it at query time, or making a VIEW that includes the calculation of this column.

Comment: Thanks for response. The main reason of this requirement is that, when we upload files to SFTP, we do not want duplicate files to be there as it will replace. I know we can append with timestamp when they uploaded, but we are trying for something order number they got uploaded. We initially thought of doing in java layer itself, however we have two parallel paths to generate same file names, and so thinking of maintaining at database for consistency across. View abstraction may work for us. Will test that. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, if it's to create files, then you are better off adding this column to a VIEW, instead of trying to keep it in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a value of fileorder to the table you'd be better off writing a query to read the table that looks like this:

```
SELECT ID, AppName, FileName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AppName ORDER BY ID) AS fileorder
FROM YOUR_TABLE                      -- Whatever your table name is
WHERE AppName in ('abc','xyz','grt') -- Any relevant WHERE clause
ORDER BY ID;
```

Unfortunately, you can't use Window Functions in a computed column, which would be the only way outside of a stored procedure or a trigger to do this.

Comment: As Tab Alleman alluded to, you could use this query above to populate the definition of a view that would give you the results you are after.

Comment: Thanks Chad for a quick response. I was thinking of Computed Column , but again it won't help much as you suggested. Probably I may go with View